# Running gps provider test produces denied access to mock location

Tags: android, unit-testing, gps, mocking

I'm trying to debug a program that is producing wonky locations out in the field by setting up test cases to mock location and see results based on accuracy.

it relies on a background service for getting the location.

The result is below:

Error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.vrin.location from uid 10168 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION
```

AndroidManifest.xml (Debug)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" tools:ignore="MockLocation"/>
```

The tests fail with the error presented above. whether it is because i have no got a mock location app selected i do not know. The code that produces the error:

```
public void getMockLocation(Location location) {
    mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    mLocationManager.addTestProvider
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    "requiresNetwork" == "",
                    "requiresSatellite" == "",
                    "requiresCell" == "",
                    "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                    "supportsAltitude" == "",
                    "supportsSpeed" == "",
                    "supportsBearing" == "",

                    android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                    android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
            );

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    newLocation.setLatitude (location.getLatitude());
    newLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

    newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    true
            );

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                    null,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );

    mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
            (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    newLocation
            );
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Nathan

Comment: On which version you are testing ?

Comment: Hey, Im using version 23

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

The permission needs to be outside the `<application>` element.

And for sure you are also required to set it via Settings. Follow inline:

```
enable Mock Locations from Settings -> Applications -> Development
```

**Note*** This may vary on different handsets.

Also not used it ever, but might be you are required to put runtime permissions for upper versions of android.